# Compiling with EJML.jar file

Tags: java, matrix, compilation

I'm working on a macbook pro

I'm very new to java and it looks like I'm going to have to learn it quick. Help would be much appreciated.

I download ejml-0.17-src.zip file, followed the instructions, and ended up with what I believe is the correct jar file,

```
 EJML.jar
```

I found a hello world-ish example from the ejml website. Since the example was just a main() function, I put the example in

```
import EJML.*;

public class MatrixTest{
    main(String[] args){
    ...
    }
}
```

and I'm now trying to compile it and then run it.

When I try to compile it I make sure that I'm in the directory with the EJML.jar file and I've tried

```
java MatrixTest.java
javac MatrixTest.java
java -classpath EJML.jar MatrixTest.java 
javac -classpath EJML.jar MatrixTest.java 
javac cp EJML.jar MatrixTest.java
java -cp EJML.jar MatrixTest.java
```

but none of these work. I'm sure this is a super-newbie question, but I'm a little tight on time.  I humbly ask for your help, with maybe a few words of explanation.

This ended up working by learning to use the API doc and changing to,

```
import org.ejml.data.*;
```

compiling with

```
javac -classpath :EJML.jar MatrixTest.java
```

and running with,

```
java -classpath :EJML.jar MatrixTest
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you defined "not working" and shared what the error message is if there is one, but for one thing your `import` is wrong. You don't import based on jar names, you import based on the packages and classes within.

You can see in the [API docs](http://efficient-java-matrix-library.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/ver0.17/index.html) that the base package is `org.ejml`.

Then when you use specific classes, you need to look at which package they're in. `DenseMatrix64F` is not in the base package, it's in `org.ejml.data`.

Comment: @Deli your comment didn't work as planned, but it's better to edit the info into your question anyway

Comment: jar tf EJML.jar and get a list of folders and files all of which originate from the org folder.  I now put "import org.ejml.*;" and I still get errors.  When I try to compile with javac -classpath EJML.jar MatrixTest.java
I get

Comment: That worked! Thank you.  So it looks like I will need to look at API docs more often. I also got it running with "java -classpath :EJML.jar MatrixTest"